# I have a problem with inserting data into a MS Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

When I click on sign in button it says syntax error in insert into statement:

```
protected void sign_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"C:\\access Databases\\myproject\\myproject.accdb\"");

        OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO client (ID, Username, Password, email, name) VALUES ('2', '"+username_txt.Text+"', '"+password_txt.Text+"', '"+email_txt.Text+"', '"+name_txt.Text+"')", con);  

        // Opening Connection  
        con.Open();

        // Executing the SQL query  
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
    catch( Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't construct your queries like that. You should be using parameterized queries. Building your queries the way you are leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Please think about what happens if someone submits a username with an apostrophe in it...

Comment: In general, you should always provide the exception stack with any Question that has to do with an error.

Comment: Name and Password are reserved words in access. You need to enclose them in square brachets. Also you have a more serious problem. Do not concatenate strings to build your values. Use parameterized query or try what happens if the input for name is _Muad'Dib_

Comment: In addition to the SQL Injection problem (wich is a real issue), you may want to look into your exception handling: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | InvalidSyntax erros sounds very much like Boneheaded Exceptions from that classificataion. And those should not be caught.

Comment: Also you really should not be using **MS Access** as backend database for a ASP.Net project. It is the product to get people hooked on Databases, not the product to replace SQL Server. You will run into the limits sooner rather then later.

Comment: @Christopher i do not use it for professional work it is just for class and the professor wants us to use **MS Access**

Comment: Okay, if it is in a class, you have no choice. However then I have doubt the abiltiy of the Teacher a bit. Even a MySQL DB would be a better starting database and is actually cheaper then Access (at actually nothing). And it is not like it is hard to initialize and reset a DB to a common starting state, so no need to transfer Access files either for code to work.

Answer (score 3):

`name` in your `INSERT` statement `INSERT INTO client(ID, Username , Password , email , name )` happens to be a [Reserved Word In MS Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words) and so the error. You must escape it using `[]` like `[name]`

As well, stop using string concatenation for passing user inputs. Rather use *Parameter Bindings* to prevent *SQL Injection*

Comment: i did not work , i deleted `name` from the database but error still the same

Comment: @muaazDeyab `password` as well is a reserved word which needs escaping